# Program to List the question based on common answer

Tags: python, pandas

read dataframe of excel file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("some.xlsx" )
df
```

to list the question with common answer

```
df[df["Answer"]=="Please visit our [FAM Application Wikipages] 
(https://wiki.siemens.com/display/en/FAM+Application)."]
```

Here, I want to print the questions with common answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try [`df.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Answer').agg(list)
```

For example:

```
>>> df
    y  x
0   a  1
1   b  1
2   c  1
3   d  2
4   e  2
5   f  3
6   g  3
7   h  3
8   i  3
9   j  3
10  k  4
11  l  5
12  m  5
13  n  6
>>> df.groupby('x').agg(list)
                 y
x                 
1        [a, b, c]
2           [d, e]
3  [f, g, h, i, j]
4              [k]
5           [l, m]
6              [n]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked can you please tell me how this function works?

Comment: I have provided a link to the documentation. So basically, groupby groups the data by specified column name, and if you apply an aggregate function, like `list` in this case, it binds the grouped objects of common key inside lists. You can find more on the documentation link I provided.
And you can upvote/accept if you found it helpful.